# Behavior of Array.prototype.map() function with JS Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying the following code:

```
 let obj ={};
    let newIngredients = ["Hello", "Distraction", "Nothing", "Love"].map(el => {
        obj.count= Math.random()*el.length;
        obj.ingredient= el;
        return obj;
    });
    console.log(newIngredients);
```

and this is the output I get:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {count: 1.4648989727265578, ingredient: "Love"}
1: {count: 1.4648989727265578, ingredient: "Love"}
2: {count: 1.4648989727265578, ingredient: "Love"}
3: {count: 1.4648989727265578, ingredient: "Love"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This is not what I wanted. But when I type in the following,

```
let obj;
let newIngredients = ["Hello", "Distraction", "Nothing", "Love"].map(el => {
      obj = {
               count: Math.random()*el.length,
               ingredient: el
            } ;
      return obj;
 });
 console.log(newIngredients);
```

It returns the following output, which I actually want:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {count: 4.2813861024052615, ingredient: "Hello"}
1: {count: 5.850654082147917, ingredient: "Distraction"}
2: {count: 6.646446034466489, ingredient: "Nothing"}
3: {count: 1.7062874250924214, ingredient: "Love"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Can anyone please explain why is this difference in behavior between the two code snippets?

Answer (score 11):

In your first example, you only created **one** object, then put it in the array four times:

```
let obj ={}; // <===== Creates the one object
let newIngredients = ["Hello", "Distraction", "Nothing", "Love"].map(el => {
    obj.count= Math.random()*el.length;
    obj.ingredient= el;
    return obj; // <===== Puts it in the array four times
});
console.log(newIngredients);
```

Since there's only one object, each time you did `obj.ingredient = el;` you *updated* the property, replacing the previous value it had.

The result looks something like this in memory:

```
                                            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
obj:Ref11654−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−+−+−>|         (object)          |
                                  / / / /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  | | | |   | count: 1.4648989727265578 |
                                  | | | |   | ingredient: "Love"        |
                                  | | | |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  | | | |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | | | |
newIngredients−−−>|   (array)   | | | | |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | | | |
                  | 0: Ref11654 |−+ | | |
                  | 1: Ref11654 |−−−+ | |
                  | 2: Ref11654 |−−−−−+ |
                  | 3: Ref11654 |−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

It's exactly like doing this:

```js
let first = {};
first.a = 1;
let second = first;
second.a = 2;
console.log(first.a); // 2, not 1
```

Your second example creates an object for each call to the `map` callback, which is correct, although there's no need for the `obj` variable and having it is a bit misleading. So:

```
let newIngredients = ["Hello", "Distraction", "Nothing", "Love"].map(el => {
    return {
        count: Math.random()*el.length,
        ingredient: el
    };
});
console.log(newIngredients);
```

or with a concise arrow function:

```
let newIngredients = ["Hello", "Distraction", "Nothing", "Love"].map(el => ({
    count: Math.random()*el.length,
    ingredient: el
}));
console.log(newIngredients);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to Array.prototype.map() but instead related to Object behaviour in javascript.

For example if you run this

```js
let obj = {};
let prev = obj;
let newIngredients = ["Hello", "Distraction", "Nothing", "Love"].map(el => {
  obj = {
    count: Math.random() * el.length,
    ingredient: el
  };
  if (obj === prev) {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
  prev = obj;
  return obj;
});
console.log(newIngredients);
```

And run this

```js
let obj = {};
let prev = obj;
let newIngredients = ["Hello", "Distraction", "Nothing", "Love"].map(el => {
  obj.count = Math.random() * el.length;
  obj.ingredient = el;
  if (obj === prev) {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
  prev = obj;
  return obj;
});
console.log(newIngredients);
```

You can clearly see in the first result, It's returning false because Object creation syntax, i.e

`let a = { }` is equal to

`let a = new Object();`

In the true one, you're just updating the previous object which is the same object being referenced by all your array elements and being updated altogether.

Hopefully, this makes it clear.